# Слово "асимметрия"

Tags: орфоэпия

Правда ли, что нужно говорить "асимметрИя", а не "асиммЕтрия"?

Comment: Попрошу обратить внимание, что слово написано неверно. А правильно - АСИММЕТРИЯ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если самостоятельно поискать, то можно выяснить, что действительно правильным произношением является асимметр***и***я. Например, можете воспользоваться [Яндекс.словарями](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/). Ну, или [грамотой.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&zar=x&word=%E0%F1%E8%EC%EC%E5%F2%F0%E8%FF).

Еще хочу сказать, что со словами вроде "энтропия" и "энтальпия" есть разные варианты постановки ударений. Скажем так, московская и питерская школы. Говорю как человек, проучившийся какое-то время на химическом факультете СПбГУ и обративший внимание на произношение. Но в словаре, тем не менее, как правильный дается только один вариант. А именно энтроп***и***я и энтальп***и***я. Не я один обратил на это внимание. Вот [тут](http://oper.ru/oforum/read.php?thread_id=1049523713#p6744748) тоже об этом же говорять. Но это уже можно списать на профессиональный слэнг.

Comment: А с какого боку тут энтропия?

Comment: Хотел проиллюстрировать подвижность ударения, в частности, в случае профессионального слэнга. Точно могу сказать, что "ассиметрия" может встречаться в геологии, кристаллографии и математике. А уж как представители этих занятий произносят данное слово не имел возможности проверить

Answer (score 1):

По словарю правильно "асимметрИя", но с этими ударениями не так всё просто.

Слова "симмЕтрия" и "фотогрАфия" тоже из греческого языка, но ударения в них стоят иначе. Согласно переводчику Google, по-гречески произносится "симметрИя" и "фотографИя".

Может быть, всё проще и ударение в слове "асимметрИя" пришло из профессиональной речи математиков? В институте нам сказали, что в математики говорят "комплЕксные числа", а не "кОмплексные", так же как моряки в своей профессиональной речи говорят не "кОмпас", а "компАс".

Маленькое дополнение: в некоторых словарях всё-таки есть оба варианта ударения.

Comment: А кто говорит, что "всё так просто"? Вот аналогии ваши - это отнбдь не всегда правильно, Тем более такие  далекие. Ну при чем тут "компас" и "комплексные числа"?

Answer (score 0):

Асимметрия (и симметрИя) пока ещё считается единственным нормативным вариантом. Но, боюсь, в не столь отдаленном будущем, норма изменится вслед за массовым произношннием.

Характерный пример. Главный редактор gramota.ru, человек безусловно грамотный, в гостях передачи 5-го канала ошибся в ответе на прямой вопрос "как правильно", сказав, что норма "симмЕтрия".

Comment: Как-то даже произнести тяжело "сИмметрия".

Comment: Почему? Как чьерту нерусскому мне такое произношения проще. К тому же по-английски /ˈsɪmɪtɹɪ/, т.е. с ударением на первом слоге, но без нажима.

Comment: Остальные слоги как-то невнятно звучат после ударения, по этому же причине мне не очень нравится ударение в слове "вероисповЕдание", где "...дание" звучит как "данье".

Comment: Поэтому у меня орфоэпическое произношение. Т.е. не "кАрОвА", а "кОрОвА".

> вероисповЕдание

100% был уверен, что ударение на А: вероисповед***а***ние. Оказывается, правильно - вероиспов***e***дание. УПС.

Comment: >>>Как-то даже произнести тяжело "сИмметрия".

Это описка. "СиммЕтрия", конечно. Простите.

Comment: Ввели нас тут в заблуждение, понимаете ли.

Comment: @behemothus, почему ошибся? У Аванесова, например, оказалось два варианта, но первый как раз "симмЕтрия".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *почему ошибся?* Да хотя бы потому, что их два. Артём, это было написано по пустяковому поводу четыре года назад, когда еще ресурс только только осваивался. Что Вы сечас так придирчивы к таким вещам? Возможно, сейчас я бы выбрал другую формулировку,  но по сути уверен. Я еще в школьные годы  разбирался с этими *симметрИями*. Аванесова сейчас посмотрю.  Какое издание у Вас?!

Comment: @behemothus, да я не придираюсь, просто хочу понять правду. Понял вас теперь. Значит, он сказал, что **только** один вариант, и в этом ошибка. Согласен тогда, что он неправ. А Аванесова я смотрю онлайн, ссылку просто в закладки положил. Раньше вообще не знал про такой словарь, видимо, кто-то тут подсказал. ;)